# Frida Server Application Crashed while hooking with Android Device

Tags: javascript, android, adb, genymotion, frida

I'm trying to pentest and Hook my android application method using frida. But when i do execute the command from command prompt in windows then my application get crashed and intended method is not executed from the apk.

I want to start my second activity by hook returning true from the frida script. Please help me to correct my code or with valid solution correction.

**My app code:**

```
package com.g.fridaplay;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(check())
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,VaultActivity.class));
        else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed access",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    boolean check(){
        String pass="asdf@123";
        if(pass.equals("asdf"))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

**Frida java script: vault.js**

```
Java.perform(function() {

       var theClass = Java.use("com.g.fridaplay.MainActivity");

       theClass.check.implementation = function(v) {
            console.log("In function check() ");
             return true;
         }

       console.log("Exploit Completed.. finished");
})
```

**Frida script command used**

```
//adb
./frida-server-15.1.3-android-x86 &

//python>script
frida -U --no-pause -l vault.js -f com.g.fridaplay
```

**Command output**

```
C:\Python39\Scripts>frida -U --no-pause -l vault.js -f com.g.fridaplay
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 15.1.3 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at https://frida.re/docs/home/
Spawned `com.g.fridaplay`. Resuming main thread!
[Android::com.g.fridaplay]-> Exploit Completed.. finished
Process crashed: Bad access due to invalid address

***
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.1.1/NMF26Q/76:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 1657, tid: 1657, name: re-initialized>  >>> <pre-initialized> <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x80000000
    eax 00000000  ebx 00000679  ecx 00000679  edx 0000000b
    esi ffdea80c  edi ffdea5a0
    xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
    eip f49ecbb9  ebp ffdea620  esp ffdea538  flags 00000296

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000bb9  [vdso:f49ec000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    #01 pc 0007f9d8  /system/bin/linker (__dl_syscall+40)
    #02 pc 000046a1  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZL24debuggerd_signal_handleriP7siginfoPv+1201)
    #03 pc 0000b7fd  /system/bin/app_process32_xposed (InvokeUserSignalHandler+317)
    #04 pc 000ff441  /system/lib/libart.so (offset 0x10a000)
***
[Android::com.g.fridaplay]->

Thank you for using Frida!
```

**My setup:**

- emulator: genymotion android 7.1 (x86)
- frida version 15.1.3
- platform: windows 10
- apk made: arctic fox 2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was with emulator. I just switched from android 7.1 device to android 10 genymotion device.